# Ruby: how to use gsub method on symbol inside string interpolation #{}

Tags: ruby, symbols, gsub, string-interpolation

I'm I'm trying to iterate through a hash, printing out keys and values in a formatted list. My understanding was that string interpolation #{} would implicitly convert the symbols to strings. However, when I run the code below (slightly abbreviated):

```
holiday_hash = {
  :winter => {:new_years => ["Party Hats", "Champagne"]}
}
holiday_hash.each do |key,value|
  value.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key.gsub("_", " ")}: #{value.join(', ')}"
  end 
end
```

I receive this error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for :new_years:Symbol
```

Can someone explain the issue? Do I need to explicitly convert the key to a string before running .gsub on it? (i.e. use ' key.to_str.gsub ... ').

My expected/desired output is as follows:

```
New Years: Party Hats, Champagne
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that within string interpolation, a *single* symbol will be stringified.

```
>> s = :hello
=> :hello
>> "#{s}"
=> "hello"
```

But you have to remember that the *entire expression* inside the brackets is evaluated *before* it is stringified. This is why you see:

```
>> "#{s.gsub('u','e')}"
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for :hello:Symbol
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

So you must manually stringify before applying `gsub`.

Comment: Ah, got it. I didn't realize the _entire expression_ was evaluated first. Makes total sense now. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4):

You have it exactly.  The key in that hash is a symbol (:new_years).  You must first:

```
puts "#{key.to_s.gsub("_", " ")}: #{value.join(', ')}"
```